# Jboss EAP 6.4 Server logs are not properly updated

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6

JBoss startup and Server logs are not getting updated completely like started in XXXX ms. But all the services are being deployed successfully. Is there any way to debug why the logs are not printing?

Thanks,
Kusuma

Comment: What does your logging configuration look like? With CLI you can have a look with `/subsystem=logging:read-resource(recursive=true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just check on your the logging subsystem configuration in your standalone.xml.

If that's not the issue, this is probably a problem with your application configuration and not JBoss, probably you just have to exclude some logging libraries in your jboss-deployment-structure.xml, to use the provided and not the jboss instance libs.